# Remove selected items from array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array of object from which i have to remove selected object and create new array of object.

```
//Get all items from 'Product' dropdown
var allItems = [{ text: "India", value: "10" }, { text: "Canada", value: "12" }, { text: "US", value: "17" }, { text: "Austria", value: "18" }, { text: "South Africa", value: "14" }];

var itemsToRemove = ["17", "10"];

var newItems = [{ text: "Canada", value: "12" }, { text: "Austria", value: "18" }, { text: "South Africa", value: "14" }];
```

Comment: Are you having a particular problem, and if so what have you tried?  Or are you just out of ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var newItems = allItems.filter(function(e) {
    // A.indexOf(x) == -1 if x is not found in A
    return itemsToRemove.indexOf(e.value) === -1;
});
```

```js
var allItems = [
  { text: "India", value: "10" },
  { text: "Canada", value: "12" },
  { text: "US", value: "17" },
  { text: "Austria", value: "18" },
  { text: "South Africa", value: "14" }
];

var itemsToRemove = ["17", "10"];

var newItems = allItems.filter(function(e) {
    return itemsToRemove.indexOf(e.value) === -1;
});

console.log( newItems );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use splice for properly deleting and indexing javascript array.

```js
var allItems = [{
  text: "India",
  value: "10"
}, {
  text: "Canada",
  value: "12"
}, {
  text: "US",
  value: "17"
}, {
  text: "Austria",
  value: "18"
}, {
  text: "South Africa",
  value: "14"
}];

var itemsToRemove = ["17", "10"];

for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < itemsToRemove.length; j++) {
    if (allItems[i].value == itemsToRemove[j])
      allItems.splice(i, 1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Dont you think this will remove 0th index ? from the array rather than the one your trying to remove ?

Comment: It should be something like this allItems.splice(i, 1);

Comment: I accidentally missed it. Thank you for your correction :)

Comment: `filter` approach will be much cheaper to execute.

Comment: Thnakyou for the solution i would wish to add one thing & i.e. if we want to remove the object we can create a variable which takes object and pass the same variable as array in itemsToRemove  remaining part will be the same.                                                  ```var objectToRemove= {text:"Canada",value:"12"};```
```var temsToRemove  = [objectToRemove];```

Answer (score 0):

Try It.

```
var allItems = [{
      text: "India",
      value: "10"
    }, {
      text: "Canada",
      value: "12"
    }, {
      text: "US",
      value: "17"
    }, {
      text: "Austria",
      value: "18"
    }, {
      text: "South Africa",
      value: "14"
    }];

    var itemsToRemove = ["17", "10"];

    for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
        if(itemsToRemove.indexOf(allItems[i].value) >= 0) {
            allItems.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for you answers, this is how i solved it.

```
var newItems = allItems.filter(function(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsToRemove.length; i++)
       if (itemsToRemove[i] == item.value) return false;
    return true;
});
```